Buffer Preparation Acetate pH 4.8 for alkaline lysis
This question might sound silly to many, but here we go.
Could someone please tell me the correct way to prepare 5M Potassium Acetate buffer pH 4.8 (3M w.r.t Potassium and 5M w.r.t. Acetate) for plasmid mini-prep?
Does the buffer need to be pH 4.8 or can you use a different pH?

Generally we look for evidence that you've made some attempt to answer the question yourself - have a look at Current Protocols, Cold Spring Harbor protocols or a copy of Molecular Cloning A Laboratory Manual, or even do a search for something along the lines of "prepare 5 M potassium acetate"

Hi, I am sorry that I wasn't being specific. I was wondering what the pH of the above mentioned solution should be? Mixing 60ml of 5M of KCH3COO- , 11.5 ml glacial acetic acid and 28.5 ml water results in a solution of pH 5.2. I am having problems with my plasmid preps and have read elsewhere that the pH of the said solution should be 4.8. I find it difficult to adjust pH of this solution to 4.8 as adding water to make up to the required volume resulted in pH going down from 4.8. Is it ok to use this solution with pH 5.2 or should the pH be strictly 4.8?

In that case you should dissolve the acetate and titrate pH with the acetic acid. The chemistry works by alkaline lysis, you then neutralize with acetate, so yes, you do need the pH to be correct otherwise you risk nicking the plasmids. Make sure you use fresh NaOH in the alkaline step - it does degrade with exposure to air when in solution.

The pH of the buffer should be at least close to 4.8 as the protocol relies on alkaline (NaOH) lysis of the bacteria, followed by neutralization of the alkali by addition of acid. If the pH is not correct you won't have enough acid to fully neutralize the alkali.
If you do not correctly or promptly (within the recommended 5 min) neutralize the NaOH, you risk damage to the plasmid by hydrolysis.  If your pH is not correct at either the alkaline step or the neutralization step then your protocol will not give good yields.
I find it best to neutralize within a couple of minutes of lysis, having determined that you have lysed as many bacteria as possible in this time. The best way to do this is ensure that you have fully resuspended the bacteria in the GET (resuspension) buffer with no lumps floating around, which means that you can add the neutralization shortly after adding the lysis solution and mixing.
